Is there a way to download all the images and pdf files located in links in cells from a Google Sheets Spreadsheet?

I have a spreadsheet with a column filled with several URL links pointing to some image files and pdf files uploaded via Google Forms and located in a folder in my Google Drive.
Since these files are mixed with other files uploaded via the same form it's very difficult to retrieve them manually when browsing the folder.
So, I am wondering whether there is a way, using Google app script, to download to a separate folder the files whose links are in the cells from that spreadsheet.
Thank you so much.

You can start by creating a Google Apps script by opening Google Sheets then go to "Extensions" to create a new script. By writing the script, it'll read the URLs from the spreadsheet, fetches the files, and saves them to a specified folder.
You can try this sample script
function downloadFilesFromFormResponses() {
  // Replace these placeholders with your actual values
  const SHEET_NAME = "Sheet1"; // Name of the spreadsheet containing URLs
  const URL_COLUMN = 1; // Column number (1-based) containing image/PDF URLs
  const DOWNLOAD_FOLDER_ID = "YOUR_DOWNLOAD_FOLDER_ID"; // ID of the destination folder

  // Get the spreadsheet and the URL column
  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(SHEET_NAME);
  const urlColumn = sheet.getRange(1, URL_COLUMN, sheet.getLastRow());
  const urls = urlColumn.getValues();

  // Loop through each URL
  for (const url of urls) {
    const fileUrl = url[0]; // Assuming only one URL per cell (adjust if needed)

    // Check if it's an image or PDF URL (modify as needed)
    if (fileUrl.endsWith(".jpg") || fileUrl.endsWith(".png") || fileUrl.endsWith(".pdf")) {
      const filename = fileUrl.split("/").pop(); // Extract filename from URL
      const destinationFile = DriveApp.getFolderById(DOWNLOAD_FOLDER_ID).createFile(filename, UrlFetchApp.fetch(fileUrl).getBlob());
      Logger.log("Downloaded file: " + filename);
    } else {
      Logger.log("Skipping non-image/PDF URL: " + fileUrl);
    }
  }
}


Be cautious when granting the script "Manage files" permission. It allows the script to create and modify files in your Drive. Make sure you understand the security implications before running the script.

Hi, Thanks for your anwer. I have replaced the seet name, the column number and the id folder and it doesn0t work. The thing is that the URLs are not listed with the extensions of the files but by their drive IDs. Could be do a version of the script that downloads all of the URLs instead? Let's forget about the jpg pdf restriction. Thanks
